# How can I make an async Task return true or false?

Tags: c#

I am calling a task like this in my method:

```
if (Settings.mode.IsPractice() && App.practiceRunning != true)
{
   // I want to call this method and check if it returned true or false
   await IsPractice();
}

private async Task IsPractice()
{
    // I want to return true or false from here
}
```

How can I return from the method based on the value of the IsPractice() returning a true or false? Looks like the async method returns just a Task but I need to know if it ran and returned a true or a false.

Comment: Use Task<bool> instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the generic Task type:

```
if (Settings.mode.IsPractice() && App.practiceRunning != true)
{
    if (await IsPractice()) {
        // Do something here
    }
}

private async Task<bool> IsPractice()
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 private static async Task<bool> IsPractice()
    {
     return true;   
    }
```

and in async method receive like this

```
bool x =  await IsPractice();
```

Answer (score 1):

just add `<bool>`

```
private async Task<bool> IsPractice()
{
    return true;
}
```

or just use `async bool`

```
private async bool IsPractice()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `private async bool IsPractice()` give you a compiler error: `CS1983 The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>`?